# session_destroy() with multiple sessions

Tags: php, session, logout

I have 3 login forms in my page, clicking logout is destroying all the sessions and logging them all out. 
I know that session_destroy() destroys all the data associated with the current session but could i give it a parameter or is there any way to specify which session to destroy?
I have tried using unset without the session_destroy but it won't logout the user

**Code edited:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['auth'])){
        if($_GET['auth']=='parent'){
        session_name('parent');
        session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['parent']))
                unset($_SESSION['parent']); 
                session_destroy();
    }}
    if(isset($_GET['auth'])){
        if($_GET['auth']=='employee'){
        session_name('employee');
        session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['employee']))
                unset($_SESSION['employee']); 
                session_destroy();
    }}
    if(isset($_GET['auth'])){
        if($_GET['auth']=='student'){
        session_name('student');
        session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['student']))
                unset($_SESSION['student']); 
                session_destroy();
    }}

    header("Location: login.php");
    ?>
```

I have added session_name to get different sessions, i am able to destroy the session but i can't have multiple sessions in the same page!

Comment: You have one session.

Comment: You have a single session.

Comment: Remember: A session is what the client gets. Your site visitor will only be a student, an employee, OR a parent. They cannot be a combination of them. Even if it was possible to be a combination (parent AND employee), PHP will only ever issue one session to the client.

Comment: Do you want to remove sessions others than the current user? You could directly erase the *session_path*/sessions but this is probably not what you want

Comment: oops! so changing the session can't be done just by changing the parameter? does session_name help?

Comment: I think you need to look at using custom cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Please use session_start(); once at the top of the page.
After successful login, please check all the sessions that is set, for example in your case.

```
$_SESSION['parent'];
$_SESSION['employee'];
$_SESSION['student'];
```

session_name(''); will override the previous session's name, so you don't have to use session_name here.
If you check there is a value for specific session or the session name is exist 
    unset($_SESSION('your_session_key'));
Hope it will work.
Thanks