# Unset one of multiple PHP sessions

Tags: php, session

I have two session_name active (admin; non-admin). I would like to reset the non-admin (e.g. when admin logs into non-admin account to make a change).

Before using session_name I was using a single session, but found admin had to re-authenticate as non-admin was using 'session_destroy();' on completion of script.

Using session_name, I need a new way to destroy the non-admin session.

Would this work?

```
 unset($GLOBALS[_SESSION][$sessionVariableName]);
```

or

```
session_name($sessionVariableName);
session_start();
session_unset();
```

Is there a better way to do this? i.e. handling multiple sessions.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is already a superglobal. `$GLOBALS['_SESSION']` is just redundant... And why not just have two sections in your single sessions: `$_SESSION['super']['super stuff goes here']` and `$_SESSION['regular']['regular stuff goes here']`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040353/session-destroy-with-multiple-sessions

Comment: Ok, so instead of separate named sessions, use a single session array. I was hoping there is a way to 'destroy' the named session (`session_name`) in use - this way my admin can manage multiple apps without many changes to code.